# Retrieving Facebook Marketing API leads

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-marketing-api

I've been retrieving Facebook leads from the marketing API using this link - w/ php and curl - https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/THE_FORM_ID/leads?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

And all of a sudden last night the response has been blank whereas before it was showing all the leads from our marketing campaigns. Any idea what could be going on?

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

Comment: try adding a filter for time_created  greater than yesterday and see if anything shows up. Also, use the latest Graph API version (which is 2.10)

Answer (score 0):

since you are using curl, try doing something like this and see if this returns any results

```
 $ret = exec("curl -G -d 'limit=100' -d 'access_token=" . $access_token . "' \
            -d 'filtering=[{\"field\":\"time_created\",\"operator\":\"GREATER_THAN\",\"value\":\"" . date("Y-m-d", time() - (24 * 3600 * 30)) . "T" . date("H:i:s", time() - (24 * 3600 * 30)) . "+0000\"}]' \
            https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/" . $form_id . "/leads");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, still blank data for every lead form. It's really bizarre. I'm wondering if this was depreciated. No error message, just a blank return.

Comment: Also when I use the link export to csv https://www.facebook.com/ads/lead_gen/export_csv/?id=MY ID&type=form&source_type=graph_api - leads show up so I know the data exists.